# android nmea GPS

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager, nmea

Hi am using a locationManager with a Nmea listener. Everything seems to work fine but here is the issue.

I log out the messages in my logcat and i notice something very strange... The messages seems broken or lacking information

example from the logcat.

```
09-24 11:41:36.899: D/BLUE(3153): LocationManager $GPGGA,094138.0,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*7F
09-24 11:41:37.899: D/BLUE(3153): LocationManager $GPGGA,094139.0,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*7E
09-24 11:41:38.899: D/BLUE(3153): LocationManager $GPGGA,094140.0,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*70
09-24 11:41:39.899: D/BLUE(3153): LocationManager $GPGGA,094141.0,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*71
09-24 11:41:40.899: D/BLUE(3153): LocationManager $GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*66
09-24 11:41:42.899: D/BLUE(3153): LocationManager $GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*66
09-24 11:41:43.899: D/BLUE(3153): LocationManager $GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*66
09-24 11:41:44.899: D/BLUE(3153): LocationManager $GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*66
09-24 11:41:45.909: D/BLUE(3153): LocationManager $GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*66
```

As far as i know. The format of the GPGGA should be something like this

```
$GPGGA,123519,4807.038,N,01131.000,E,1,08,0.9,545.4,M,46.9,M,,*47
```

Now i tried other types like GLL and its the same issue. I also tried just reading the bytes directly with bluetooth but its the same thing.

Anyone have similair issues with Nmea messages?

Comment: I doubt that is the case cause i been testing it on testViews aswell. Its the same problem there aswell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the GPS does not have a fix. Are you certain you have a good enough signal? Please verify outdoors under an open sky.

Comment: It might very well be the signal! I am sitting indoor inside a building where i did have some problems before getting a location on the internal gps on another application. If this is true it will make testing very troublesome...  Maybe that is why my first attempt on using a parser failed, because the message i was parsing was not complete?

Comment: @user1271363, well i suggest you to check outside under open sky, that will give you accurate result. atleast in the beginning you should have open sky.

Comment: I think i will put a battery in the gps and go down once i tested the parser on a premade string. Funny i never thought about the signal being strong enough ^^.

Comment: I just tested the parse on a premade NMEA strign and it extracts the location fine now... I feel very stupid... and i am sure when i go out under the sky it will work fine.. Thank you for your help guys

Comment: @user1271363 I have same problem but with one difference, even if I am under the open sky I am not getting GPGGA sentences at all, the behaviour on my Pixel is really weird, when I am in the room I am getting some incomplete GPGGA sentences when I am going out I am getting nothing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63917764/gpgga-and-gprmc-sentences-are-not-received-in-onnmeamessage

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the signal, wait 1 or 2 minutes and data will be completed